# how do i switch from 32 bit to 64 bit for steam

Tags: 64-bit, games, steam

Hello I'm new to using Ubuntu and Linux in general. I am trying to play steam games however, when I run steam and start a game it doesn't run as it says  something on the lines of 'cannot open wrong version'.

I have:

- Gone onto the steam website and it says that it no longer support 32 bit OS's

I have a Compaq presario CQ62 running a Linux distro called 'X-tra PC 32

I am getting tired of playing indie games that i cant download. Can someone suggest a solution please?

My main goal is to just play games .I have tried everything I can find from my research on Google to no avail.

Comment: This question is **off-topic** I believe; as X-tra PC is not Ubuntu, nor an official flavor.  This site is for Ubuntu user questions. I'd suggest asking on Stack Exchange's Unix & Linux Q&A site

Answer (score 2):

You can't because the CPU shipped with your computer, the Intel Celeron 900 (Pentium Ⅲ Coppermine), doesn't support the amd64 instruction set that is necessary to run the amd64 edition of Ubuntu or any other operating system relying on the same instruction set (e. g. SteamOS).

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Comment: ok... but is there a way i can install any 64 bit software at all , example: Google Chrome

Comment: @user802149: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.